# Adjusting Website Display at 100% Zoom

Tags: plugins

I'm currently facing an issue with the display of my website at 100% zoom in most browsers. At this zoom level, the site feels too cramped and doesn't match the aesthetic I prefer.

I've noticed that my website looks much better and more spacious when the browser is set to 75% zoom (Picture 2 attached). What I'm seeking is a way to achieve the same visual appearance and spaciousness at 100% zoom as I experience at 75% zoom.

For better clarity, I've attached two pictures:

Picture 1: Website at 100% zoom (current display)

Picture 2: Website at 75% zoom (preferred display)

I understand that altering the zoom via CSS can be challenging. I'm looking for suggestions or workarounds to maintain the default browser zoom at 100% while achieving the visual appearance of my website at 75% zoom.

Any help, tips, or guidance to achieve this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time and assistance!

[image: My website at 100% zoom]
[image: My website at 75% zoom]

Comment: There’s no shortcut unfortunately. You’ll just need to update your theme’s stylesheet to reduce the size of things by 25-33%.